# How to get event delegation to handle Dojo FilteringSelect changes?

Tags: javascript, dojo, event-handling

I've got a Dojo Form filled with various inputs, all Dojo widgets; one of them is the dijit/form/FilteringSelect.  I have defined an event delegate handler on the form to capture specific events from all the Dojo widgets within the Form. The delegate uses the CSS style selector syntax to identify all the types of inputs and events that it will handle, but I cannot find the right selector that will capture choices selected from the FilteringSelect widgets. Same problem with dijit/form/Select and dijit/form/ComboBox widgets.

I've created a demonstration at https://jsfiddle.net/gregorco/a3uxvzv3/1/ which contains:

```
<div id="testDiv">
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="testForm" data-dojo-id="testForm"  encType="multipart/form-data" 
action="" method=""> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" data-dojo-id="yellowid" id="yellowid" name="color" value="4"/><label id="corpLabel"  for="yellowid">Yellow</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" id="redid" name="color" value="5"/><label class="forInput" for="redid">Red</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" data-dojo-id="blueid" id="blueid" name="color" value="6"/><label id="llpLabel"  for="blueid">Blue</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" id="greenid" name="color" value="7"/><label  for="greenid">Green</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dojo FilteringSelect</td>
    <td>
        <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="fruit" name="fruit">
<option value="AP">Apples</option>
<option value="OR" selected>Oranges</option>
<option value="PE" >Pears</option>
</select> &nbsp; (onChange event not triggered by selection, but typing value triggers event)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dojo Select</td>
    <td>
<select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="VA" selected="selected">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dojo ComboBox</td>
    <td>
    <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" id="animal" name="animal">
<option>Dogs</option>
<option selected>Fish</option>
<option>Spiders</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

and

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/query",
"dojo/parser", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(dom, dojoOn, dojoQuery, parser, domConstruct) {

         var eventDescriptions =
             "textarea:change,"+  
             "textarea:input,"+ 
             "input:change,"+  
             "input:input,"+ 
             "div.dijitArrowButtonInner:click,"+ 
             "select:change,"+  
             "grid:onRowClick,"+
             "button:click";
var paneForm = dom.byId("testForm");
         if(typeof paneForm != "undefined" && paneForm != null) {
             dojoOn(paneForm, eventDescriptions, handleFormEvent);
         }    

function handleFormEvent(event){ 
    console.log("handleFormEvent event="+event+" currentTarget="+event.currentTarget.id+", this.value="+this.value);
    console.log("event=");
    console.dir(event);
    console.log("this=");
    console.dir(this);
    alert("Event delegate caught this event of type: "+event.type);
}
});
```

The event delegate handler does capture the event of the user typing into the FilteringSelect and Select widgets textfields, but not when a choice is selected from the list.  Is there a way to make the delegate recognize the selection action?

Comment: Any chance you can just run a loop and then just plug into each form widget's onChange (e.g., on(widget, "change")) event?

Comment: Thanks.  I could do that, but I was hoping to leverage the event delegate pattern if possible.  If necessary I'll do a loop like that.